# Call selector after CCDelayTime

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

So I have a selector that need to be perform after certain amount of delay / interval, and I still can't find the solution. Put `CCDelayTime` before the `CCCallFunc` in `CCSequence` doesn't work. But it's working at simply put something like `schedule:interval:` or `performselector:afterdelay`.

```
    if (shootDelay > kBlastBombLaunchingDelay) {
        [self createFireProgressBar];
        action = [CCSequence actions:
                  [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: kBlastBombLaunchingDelay],
                  [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(launchBomb)],
                  nil];
        //[self performSelector:@selector(launchBomb) withObject:nil afterDelay:kBlastBombLaunchingDelay];
        //[self schedule:@selector(launchBomb) interval:kBlastBombLaunchingDelay];
        shootDelay = 0;
    }

[self runAction:action];
```

Somehow, the selector `launchBomb` is not called. Sorry for the silly question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You don't seem to have called:</strike>

```
[self runAction:action];
```

### User found own solution

I think I've found the solution. Just like I said earlier, it's a silly question, the error was because of my messy algorithm. Put a lower value than kBlastBombLaunchingDelay for the CCDelayTime and change the if position to the statement which change my hero state. And it works now.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete code, there is a code under it. `[self runAction:action];`

Comment: Try printing out the value of `action` at that point: `NSLog(@"Action: %@", action);`

Comment: `Action: <CCSequence = 05898C30 | Tag = -1>` Does that -1 value means anything?

Comment: No, that is just the default value of the tag. How long is `kBlastBombLaunchingDelay `

Comment: kBlastBombLaunchingDelay  8.0f

Comment: That's 8 seconds, is that what you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, 8 seconds, and so is the `launchBomb` interval delay and `createFireProgressBar` selector. So what i'm expecting is these functions are run at sequence, `createFireProgressBar` first, then after 8 seconds, `launchBomb` selector is fired.

Comment: Is it possible the action has been deallocated within those 8 seconds? Is the object that you are calling runAction on still on the stage 8 seconds later?

Comment: Alright, I think I've found the solution. Just like I said earlier, it's a silly question, the error was because of my messy algorithm. Put a lower value than `kBlastBombLaunchingDelay ` for the `CCDelayTime` and change the `if` position to the statement which change my hero state. And it works now, thanks for your time @James Webster. :)

Comment: No bother, glad I could help and even happier that you found the solution yourself.

Comment: I've replaced my answer with yours.